# Websphere 7 cluster

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing

I have a Websphre 7 cluster with nodes running on different servers.
When a server with one node loses connection to the network, it takes about a minute, after which the Websphre knows that the member is unavailable.

How can I speed up the status updates?

UPD. The cluster is used only for EJB. EJB called from the local network.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is always going to be a tradeoff between performance during normal operations and how quickly a down cluster member is detected.

See this article, [Understanding HTTP plug-in failover in a clustered environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21219808) and [this plugin-cfg.xml reference in the WebSphere 7 InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rwsv_plugincfg.html).

From the article, the answer will involve the `ConnectTimeout`, `ServerIOTimeout`, and `RetryInterval` settings, but note the warning that:

> In an environment with busy workload or a slow network connection, setting this value too low could make the HTTP plug-in mark a cluster member down falsely. Therefore, caution should be used whenever choosing a value for ConnectTimeout.​​

Comment: Good response. It only address the Web Traffic though (between HTTP Plugin and the application server). Similar operations happen when a component in one application server talks to another component running in another cluster member(for e.g on an EJB call where the JVM affinity is not set)

Comment: Good point, @Manglu. I don't do EJBs, so I never considered that.

Comment: The cluster is used only for EJB. EJB called from the local network.